# Searching through tag using Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ransack

I'm using Ransack to perform fairly complex searches through some models. One of these models holds free text and uses the acts_as_taggable gem to tag the words.

I'm trying to create a collection selector of these words so that ransack can find any of the full text records from a subset of the tags that the user can define.

This gets me nearly there, but if I try to choose more than one word, it doesn't return any results!

```
= f.select :note_in, @freetexts.tag_counts_on(:tags), {}, {:multiple => true}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ransack is not really oriented to complex searchs. It is very probable that if you stress ransack enough you end with a harder problem that if you where doing a complex select.

For complex search I would recomment Sequel, from the same author of ransack and much better oriented to complex searchs.

Moreover, according to thes thread you are on a dead end:
[Ransack and acts-as-taggable-on issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421508/ransack-and-acts-as-taggable-on-issues)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert at all, but this non-ransack solution could work for those that need to filter by tags with the acts-as-taggable-on gem:

```
@search = MyModel.ransack(params[:q])
@result = @search.result(distinct: true).includes(:related_model)
@result = @result.tagged_with(params[:tags].split(/\s*,\s*/)) if params[:tags].present?
@result = @result.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
```

This expects a new :tags param that is out of the scope of Ransack. You can use to filter out the results that Ransack gives you.